# Remove unwanted script and iframe from html page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am creating a website, In which a hidden script and a hidden iframe is automatically inserted at the end of the page. I have not included that in my page, still they are in the page while inspect element in the browser.

This is my ending of html page

```
          .
          .
          .
          < !-- Login Box Ends Here -->
          < !--sign up / sign in Code Ends -->      
       <!-- fixed header end-->
    </body>
</html>
```

And when inspecting element in browser i am getting extra script and iframe added as

```
          .
          .
          .
          < !-- Login Box Ends Here -->
          < !--sign up / sign in Code Ends -->      
       <!-- fixed header end-->
       **<script src="https://static.dreamsadnetwork.com/chromeapp/vdstatus/contentScript.js" id="vdstatusID"></script>
       <iframe name="_rlcdn" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="http://rc.rlcdn.com/378618.html"></iframe>
       <iframe src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/userData.jsp?dlsource=dingodeals&amp;userid=NTBCNTBC&amp;ver=13.1.1.77" style="position: absolute; top: -100px; left: -100px; z-index: -10; border: none; visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></iframe>**
    </body>
</html>
```

How to remove these extras script and iframe included while running webpage in browser

Comment: Are these auto-inserted ads? :)

Comment: Service Pages for Google Chrome™ this extention did this in my case

Comment: video download helper (or similar) chrome extension adds 'static.dreamsan....' script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Browser are you using? you most probably have some adware added by extensions, so the solutions is to remove all the unwanted extensions

Comment: In chrome and firefox aurora, scripts and iframe are being inserted.

But in opera no extra sripts are included (working fine).

IN firefox aurora there are no add ons still, these are included

Comment: For example superfish is a malware installed that comes with other free applications, Check this link: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/superfish-window-shopper-adware/

Comment: So it's installed locally, you should clean your computer

Comment: There was a software moviemode installed, that was the  reason, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove iFrames like any other HTML element, and same for a script tag. Whether or not it's useful to remove the script after it might've already run is another story.